# Strange behavior from List.clear() method in java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

The problem is that the `clear()` method for `List<String> little_list` clears all elements from the said list.

I know it's not the best way to write the code, but I just wanted to try something new.
The code is used for Java Android app in Android Studio.
I monitored it via the debug tool, and it seems like the `list` gets empty after the end of the loop.

```java
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();;
List<String> little_list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
    little_list.add("Hello");
    list.add(little_list);
    little_list.clear();
}
```

If I do something like this, it works just fine:

```java
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();;
List<String> little_list;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
    little_list = new ArrayList<>();
    little_list.add("Hello");
    list.add(little_list );
}
```

I have googled about it a bit but couldn't find anything useful.

All helps are appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: `add` doesn't create some kind of copy. Your first approach is simply adding the same list object over and over again.

Comment: you mean little_list won't get added to list and then get cleared ?

Comment: You are clearing the list you added before

Comment: In your first code, you're always using the same `little_list`. You add it to `list` multiple times. And you add "Hello" to the `little_list`, but by calling `.clear()` you remove it again. So `list` ends up having 3 references to `little_list`, which after the loop will always be empty. In your second piece of code, you're creating a new instance of `ArrayList` in each loop, add one element to it. So here you'll end up having 3 instances of `ArrayList` inside `list`, and each of those 3 `ArrayList`s contain "Hello" (or rather, the same reference to the String constant).

Comment: "_you mean little_list won't get added to list and then get cleared ?_"  – It does get added to the list. And then it's cleared. That's exactly the problem. The list in `list` and the list referenced by `little_list` **are the same list** (in your first approach).

Comment: I think that answered my question.Thanks <3